# Context-free grammar for language describing a, ab, abc, ac...?

Tags: context-free-grammar, context-free-language

I'm trying to figure out what will be the CFG for a language described like that:

- only one *a*
- 0 or more *b*
- 0 or more *c*

I tried this:
`S -> a | Sb | Sc`

Or something like that:

`S -> a | B | C`

`B -> Bb`

`C -> Cc`

but it doesn't seem to work. Is there any other/better way to describe that language with a CFG?

Comment: Can you come up with a regular expression for that language? There is a single `a`. What comes before? What comes after?

Comment: use the regular expression a{1}b*c*

Answer (score 1):

A grammar for for the language of strings which have a single a, and nothing else, is simply

```
S -> a
```

Your language is different in that zero or more b's and c's are also allowed. They can come before or after the single a and can come in any order. A grammar for the language "any number of b's and c's in any order' is

```
T -> bT | cT | e
```

Because we can have any number of b's and c's on either side of our single a, this suggests we can add the productions for nonterminal T to our production for S and change the production for S to derive a with a T on either side:

```
S -> TaT
T -> bT | cT | e
```

This grammar should work. Proving this grammar is correct is left as an exercise.

There are other viable approaches. One viable approach is to make a DFA for this regular language and then rewrite it as a grammar. The grammar will be context-free if this is done in a straightforward manner.

```
q0 -> bq0
q0 -> cq0
q0 -> aq1
q1 -> bq1
q1 -> cq1
q1 -> e
```